# unable to add invoice fee tax in magento order total

Tags: magento, payment-gateway

I am working on magento 1.7. i am working on payment gateway where i have added invoice fee now i have to add tax of invoice fee in tax group  [image]

please anyone help to solve this problem here is following my code i have tried to add tax amount in taxes but still not working may be i am doing something wrong

```
<?php

class ***_******_Model_Quote_TaxTotal
    extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Tax
{

    public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {
        $quote = $address->getQuote();
        if (($quote->getId() == null)
            || ($address->getAddressType() != "shipping")
        ) {
            return $this;
        }

        $payment = $quote->getPayment();
        if (($payment->getMethod() != 'invoice')
            && (!count($quote->getPaymentsCollection()))
        ) {
            return $this;
        }

        try {
            /**
             * Instead of relying on hasMethodInstance which would not always
             * work when i.e the order total is reloaded with coupon codes, we
             * try to get the instance directly instead.
             */
            $methodInstance = $payment->getMethodInstance();
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            return $this;
        }

        if (!$methodInstance instanceof Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract) {
            return $this;
        }

        if ($methodInstance->getCode() != 'invoice') {
            return $this;
        }

        $fee = $methodInstance->getAddressInvoiceFee($address);
        if(Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/invoice/tax_class') == '' ){
            return $this;
        }

        $invoiceFee = $baseInvoiceFee = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/invoice/_fee');

        $fee = Mage::helper('invoice')->getInvoiceFeeArray($invoiceFee, $address, null);

        if (!is_array($fee)) {
            return $this;
        }
        $address->setTaxAmount($address->getTaxAmount() + 5454+ $fee['taxamount']);
        $address->setBaseTaxAmount(
            $address->getBaseTaxAmount() + 5454+ $fee['base_taxamount']
        );

        $address->setInvoiceTaxAmount($fee['taxamount']);
        $address->setBaseInvoiceTaxAmount($fee['base_taxamount']);
        return $this;
    }

}
```

and this is config.xml

```
    <sales>
        <quote>
            <totals>
                <fee>
                    <class>invoice/sales_quote_address_total_fee</class>
                </fee>
                <invoicetax>
                    <class>invoice/quote_taxTotal</class>
                    <after>subtotal,discount,shipping,tax</after>
                    <before>grand_total</before>
                </invoicetax>
            </totals>
        </quote>
    </sales>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code must be following i have following i modified your code

```
<?php

class *****_******_Model_Quote_TaxTotal extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Tax
{
    public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {
        $collection = $address->getQuote()->getPaymentsCollection();
        if ($collection->count() <= 0 || $address->getQuote()->getPayment()->getMethod() == null) {
            return $this;
        }

        $paymentMethod = $address->getQuote()->getPayment()->getMethodInstance();

        if ($paymentMethod->getCode() != 'invoice') {            
            return $this;
        }

        $store = $address->getQuote()->getStore();        

        $items = $address->getAllItems();
        if (!count($items)) {
            return $this;
        }

        $custTaxClassId = $address->getQuote()->getCustomerTaxClassId();

        $taxCalculationModel = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation');
        /* @var $taxCalculationModel Mage_Tax_Model_Calculation */
        $request = $taxCalculationModel->getRateRequest(
            $address,
            $address->getQuote()->getBillingAddress(),
            $custTaxClassId,
            $store
        );
        $InvoiceTaxClass = Mage::helper('invoice')->getInvoiceTaxClass($store);

        $InvoiceTax      = 0;
        $InvoiceBaseTax  = 0;

        if ($InvoiceTaxClass) {
            if ($rate = $taxCalculationModel->getRate($request->setProductClassId($InvoiceTaxClass))) {

                if (!Mage::helper('invoice')->InvoicePriceIncludesTax()) {
                    $InvoiceTax    = $address->getFeeAmount() * $rate/100;
                    $InvoiceBaseTax= $address->getBaseFeeAmount() * $rate/100;
                } else {
                    $InvoiceTax    = $address->getPaymentTaxAmount();
                    $InvoiceBaseTax= $address->getBasePaymentTaxAmount();
                }

                $InvoiceTax    = $store->roundPrice($InvoiceTax);
                $InvoiceBaseTax= $store->roundPrice($InvoiceBaseTax);

                $address->setTaxAmount($address->getTaxAmount() + $InvoiceTax);
                $address->setBaseTaxAmount($address->getBaseTaxAmount() + $InvoiceBaseTax);

                $this->_saveAppliedTaxes(
                    $address,
                    $taxCalculationModel->getAppliedRates($request),
                    $InvoiceTax,
                    $InvoiceBaseTax,
                    $rate
                );
            }
        }

        if (!Mage::helper('invoice')->InvoicePriceIncludesTax()) {
            $address->setInvoiceTaxAmount($InvoiceTax);
            $address->setBaseInvoiceTaxAmount($InvoiceBaseTax);
        }

        $address->setGrandTotal($address->getGrandTotal() + $address->getPaymentTaxAmount());
        $address->setBaseGrandTotal($address->getBaseGrandTotal() + $address->getBasePaymentTaxAmount());

        return $this;
    }

    public function fetch(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {        
        $store = $address->getQuote()->getStore();
        /**
         * Modify subtotal
         */

         if (Mage::getSingleton('tax/config')->displayCartSubtotalBoth($store) ||
            Mage::getSingleton('tax/config')->displayCartSubtotalInclTax($store)) {

            if ($address->getSubtotalInclTax() > 0) {
                $subtotalInclTax = $address->getSubtotalInclTax();
            } else {
                $subtotalInclTax = $address->getSubtotal()+ $address->getTaxAmount() -
                    $address->getShippingTaxAmount() - $address->getPaymentTaxAmount();
            }            

            $address->addTotal(
                array(
                    'code'      => 'subtotal',
                    'title'     => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Subtotal'),
                    'value'     => $subtotalInclTax,
                    'value_incl_tax' => $subtotalInclTax,
                    'value_excl_tax' => $address->getSubtotal()
                )
            );
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```